# Does IOTA really have a Documentation?

Tags: documentation, iota

I hear a lot about IOTA, but on the official site I found very little.

I read the WP: 
https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf

but that's just concepts, I want to know details about software like "iotacore"

https://dev.iota.org/#

The link is broken.

can anyone tell me where I find reliable information about this  cryptocurrency?

Answer (score 0):

Great IOTA tutorial playlist
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmL13yqb6OxdIf6CQMHf7hUcDZBbxHyza

IOTA tools from the playlist
https://www.mobilefish.com/services/cryptocurrency/cryptocurrency.php

IOTA and NodeJS tutorial
https://youtu.be/Z-NN0rRcwY0

Repository for above tutorial
https://github.com/iota-community/iota-workshop

Answer (score -1):

The new IOTA documentation portal is now available at https://docs.iota.org/

Answer (score -2):

IOTA is still running in beta and need to wait for the official documentation to roll out in the coming few months as mentioned in the link.

check this link for IOTA beta documentation: https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/what-is-iota

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: both of the above information does not answer me.

an Alpha, Beta or Zulu project
you need documentation for others to use.
not to use api or project with trial and error.
Imagine the main part, like IOTA CORE ..

all crypto models with bitcoin exceptions are still ALPHA.

this project is very obscure, it includes a lot of expectations and little delivery.

if anyone disagrees, post the official Iota core link that I'm sure will change my mind.